# laravel DB::connection()->getPdo()::PARAM_STR not working

Tags: laravel-5, php-7, php-5.6

The function getPdo() with PARAM_STR in laravel

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()::PARAM_STR
```

is working fine with php 7.0.0 but not working with php 5.6.16 or lesser versions. How can I get the PARAM_STR from PDO instance in laravel with php 5.6.16 or less?

I have tried

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->PARAM_STR
```

but not working for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which worked for me is this..

```
static function db ()
    {
        try {
            $db = DB::connection()->getPdo();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            self::fatal(
                "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
                "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        return $db;
    }
```

By calling..

```
$db=self::db();

$db::PARAM_STR
```

I got it solved. All inside class & method