# How can I make a database connection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database-connection

Here is my code in pure PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName', 'root', '');
```

What's the equivalent of it in Laravel?

---

Noted that, none of these won't work:

```
$dbh = DB::connection('dbName');

$dbh = DB::connection('dbName')->getPdo();
```

---

#### EDIT

Here is my codes: *(which doesn't work)*

```
// /config/database.php

'connections' => [
    'myconn' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbName'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]



// app/files/test.php

$dbh = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And here is the working version:

```
// app/files/test.php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName', 'root', '');
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: which version you use  ??

Comment: @EhsanIlahi *Laravel Framework version 5.3.4*

Comment: why not tried with config/database.php

Comment: @Rishi I did, I've a connection there named `myconn`. But when I use `$dbh = DB::connection('myconn')->getPdo();`, still it doesn't work.

Comment: did you make this default or dynamically you are changing this connection ?

Comment: @Rishi I've edited my question

Comment: did you set `DB_DATABASE` in `.env` file ? `database` value will get value from `.env` file first if found there otherwise it will be `dbname` hope you know this.

Comment: @Rishi No need. As you see in my question, I've set database connection in `database.php` file.

Comment: then it should be like this `'database' =>  'dbName',` not `'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbName'),` same for `username` and `password`

Comment: @stack: have you set `myconn` as `default` in database.php??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static function db ()
        {
            try {
                $db = DB::connection()->getPdo();
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                self::fatal(
                    "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
                    "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
                );
            }
            return $db;
        }
```

By calling..

```
$db=self::db();

$db::PARAM_STR
```

Reference [laravel DB::connection()->getPdo()::PARAM_STR not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076065/laravel-dbconnection-getpdoparam-str-not-working)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

Comment: Will be great if you explain you answer